# UITextView inside UIAlertView subclass

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitextview, uialertview

I'm trying to put a UITextView inside a custom subclass of UIAlertView that I create using a background image of mine. The UITextView is only for displaying large quantities of text (so the scrolling).
Here is the code of my subclass

```
- (id)initNarrationViewWithImage:(UIImage *)image text:(NSString *)text{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.backgroundImage = image;  
        UITextView * textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.textualNarrationView = textView;
        [textView release];
        self.textualNarrationView.text = text;
        self.textualNarrationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        self.textualNarrationView.opaque = YES;
        [self addSubview:textualNarrationView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    NSLog(@"DRAU");
    CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
    [self.backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {


    CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
    self.textualNarrationView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width - 20, imageSize.height - 20);
    self.textualNarrationView.center = CGPointMake(320/2, 480/2);


}

- (void)show{
    [super show];
    NSLog(@"SCIO");
    CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    self.center = CGPointMake(320/2, 480/2);
}
```

This is my first time subclassing a UIView, I'm surely missing something since the background image appears correctly, the UITextview also but after a fraction of a second it jumps all up (seems like a coordinate problem).

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, the UIAlert will add automatic an UITextView if there is too much text on the screen...

Comment: so where shall I add my text while initing?

Comment: For the moment I took another direction using a UILabel instead. I will post a solution if I'll find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally created my own customized version of `UIAlertView` and provided a `UITextView` inside of it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269461/subclassed-uialertview-not-drawn-correctly-in-ios-4-2) is what brought me to do so.

By doing it I experienced a weird behaviour when I was trying to attach the `UITextView` to a background `UIImageView` as a subview, it wasn't responsive to touches anymore, the way to make it work as expected was to attach it to the base view and implement the following method

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`

by making it return `YES` when encessary.