# Subclassed UIAlertView not drawn correctly in iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4, background, uialertview

I've subclassed an UIAlertView as follow:

```
@interface NarrationAlertView : UIAlertView {
    UIImage * backgroundImage; //The image I want as custom background
    UILabel * textualNarrationView; //The test I wanna be displayed on the view        
}
```

And implemented it this way :

```
- (id)initNarrationViewWithImage:(UIImage *)image{

    if (self = [super init]){
        UILabel * alertTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.textualNarrationView = alertTextLabel;
        [alertTextLabel release];
        [self addSubview:alertTextLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    /* Here I draw the image as background */
    CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
    [self.backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    /* To fit the text */
    [textualNarrationView sizeToFit];

    CGRect textRect = textualNarrationView.frame;
    textRect.origin.x = (CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(textRect)) / 2;
    textRect.origin.y = (CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(textRect)) / 2;
    textRect.origin.y -= 70;
    textualNarrationView.frame = textRect;
}

- (void)show{
    /* Showing the view */
    [super show];
    CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
}
```

On the previous versions of iOS (I'm always testing on the simulator) the subclass run fine and when shown it displayed the custom background image drawn correctly and **just text** upon it, whereas in the 4.2 version it draws the UIAlertView classic background (the blue rounded corners rectangle) **on top** of my image.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion about UIAlertView programming and UIView too will be appreciated.

**UPDATE** Has anyone got some UIAlertView replacement class to share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a similar problem with UIAlertView in iOS 4.2; we were customizing the layout, added text boxes and rearranging the buttons.

This won't be a popular answer, but due to the changes to UIAlertView, we had to abandon using it entirely for this purpose.  We always knew it was a fragile implementation since customizing/subclassing UIAlertView isn't officially supported and makes assumptions about the internal structure of the view hierarchy, but the release of 4.2 really kicked us into gear.

In the end, we implemented our own UI element to replace the customized UIAlertView.

Comment: I feared that, how have you accomplished the pop up effect combined with the background shadowed view?

Comment: We actually went a different way with the UI, what used to be a popup now slides down/slides up from the top of the screen.  I did look into replicating the pop-up effect, and found this helpful link:http://delackner.com/blog/2009/12/mimicking-uialertviews-animated-transition/

Comment: That link provided a nice animation, I combined it with this other source http://iphonedevcentral.blogspot.com/2010/08/custom-alert-views.html . Lesson learned

Answer (score 3):

Prior to iOS 4.2 UIAlertView's standard dark blue rounded rectangle was drawn in drawRect. the rounded rectangle could be removed by subclassing UIAlertView and implementing drawRect without calling super. however in 4.2 the rounded rectangle is a UIImageView subview.
the quick, easy (not best) solution: If you are not adding any UIImageView instances to your UIAlertView subclass you can simply remove the default UIImageView that is loaded by observing subview additions:

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview {
  if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
  }
}
```

Comment: It crashes when I rotate. any ideas?

Comment: sorry, this was a temporary hack that lived in my code for a short time. My 'alert' grew more complicated so i implemented my own version of UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

I got burned by this too.  I ended up writing a replacement class, which I'm sharing on github:

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView