# cocos2d scene only showing for specific width

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I start my cocos scene calling following function in a UIViewController (yes, I must call it from a UIViewController) with a 425x320 size of view.

```
-(void) runCocos2d
{
   EAGLView *glview = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];

   CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
   [director setDisplayFPS:YES];
   [director setOpenGLView:glview];

   CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
   id node = [LayerExample node];
   [scene addChild: node];

   [director runWithScene:scene];

   [self.view addSubview:glview];

}
```

It shows perfectly on the simulator but not on the device (I only get a black view there). And if I change the first line to
`EAGLView *glview = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 425, 320)];` (only change the width of the EAGLView)
It doesn't show on the simulator neither anymore.

I didn't use the templates, I configured it like in this [post](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/knowledge-base/tutorial-professional-cocos2d-xcode-project-template/learn-cocos2d-public-content/manual/1601/13472-create-a-xcode-project-template-referencing-the-cocos2d-project/).

Cocos2d output:

> 2010-12-08 17:45:01.905[16537:207] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR: Apple Computer, Inc.
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.905[16537:207] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.906[16537:207] cocos2d: GL_VERSION: OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.906[16537:207] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.906[16537:207] cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.907[16537:207] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.907[16537:207] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: NO
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.909[16537:207] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.909[16537:207] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.910[16537:207] cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.910[16537:207] cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : YES
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.910[16537:207] cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.911[16537:207] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.912[16537:207] cocos2d: cocos2d v0.99.4
>   2010-12-08 17:45:01.912[16537:207] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCTimerDirector

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270320/why-is-my-eaglview-not-rendering-anymore-in-ios-4-2)

But I have no solution since I need a 425x320 resolution

Answer (score 0):

Since the view needs to be in multiples of 32, why not make it 480x320 and then offset it so it hangs 55 pixels off the edge of the screen?

You get your view and can then just take the "dead space" into consideration when drawing.