# Why can't I see certain OpenGL ES charts in the 4.2 Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, ios-simulator

I am writing an application which contains some graphs drawn in OpenGL ES. each of these graphs are in a table cell, when I press some of those graphs, it is being opened in full screen mode. 
Everything worked perfectly since I upgraded to iOS4.2. **Now the problem is in simulator, I can't see the drawn graph in cells, but in full screen mode I do see the chart.** There are no changes no the device, it is only on the simulator and only in a case.
The behavior is the same for other Mac's here.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270320/why-is-my-eaglview-not-rendering-anymore-in-ios-4-2/4307755#4307755) to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270320/why-is-my-eaglview-not-rendering-anymore-in-ios-4-2), there has been a change in the way that 4.2 handles renderbuffers in Core Animation layers.  From the [OpenGL ES Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html):

> In iOS 4.2 and later, the performance
>   of Core Animation rotations of
>   renderbuffers have been significantly
>   improved, and are now the preferred
>   way to rotate content between
>   landscape and portrait mode. For best
>   performance, ensure the renderbuffer’s
>   height and width are each a multiple
>   of 32 pixels.

It appears that if your renderbuffer isn't an even multiple of 32 pixels, it doesn't display in the Simulator.  This is a bug in the Simulator, but you should probably make your renderbuffer a multiple of 32 in either dimension in any case to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Same things with my App. My textures are broken sporadically on the simulator (4.2). On the hardware everything looks fine.

Comment: the selected answer did really help me. So you could try it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps much, but I've seen all manner of strange behaviour on the simulator implementation of OpenGL ES: spurious images appearing; strange lighting on the first render pass; broken rendering to bitmaps, depending on when I call it. I'm no expert in OpenGL programming, so I could just be writing crap code, but there is definitely a noticeable difference in the behaviour of the simulator vs the real hardware.

Your experience suggests that maybe my problems aren't entirely my fault. :-)